# Scrape Mobile Specification from a webpage

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to get the details of all the mobiles listed in a web page, like name, price and specification. I was successful in getting names and prices, and for specification-its messed up. There are 24 listings of mobiles phones, when i try to get the specifications , it get the specifications all together in a list. I am not able to find a suitable way to separate them according to the phone that they belong to. Any help would be appriciated. Below is the function definition-

```
def get_link(self,link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    name = tree.xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']/text()")
    print name
    time.sleep(5)
    price = tree.xpath("//div[@class='_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK']/text()")[1::2]
    print price      
    time.sleep(5)
    highlights = tree.xpath("//ul[@class='vFw0gD']/li/text()")
    print highlights


'''
    dictionary={}
    for i in range(len(name)):
        dictionary[name[i]]=price[i]
    print dictionary


    return
'''
```

the link that is pass is - https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles-accessories/mobiles/pr?count=40&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=tyy%2F4io

and the output so far is -

```
['Mi A1 (Black, 64 GB)', 'Redmi Note 4 (Gold, 32 GB)', 'Mi A1 (Rose Gold, 64 GB)', 'Redmi Note 4 (Gold, 64 GB)', 'Redmi Note 4 (Black, 32 GB)', 'Honor 9i (Graphite Black, 64 GB)', 'Redmi Note 4 (Black, 64 GB)', 'Moto E4 Plus (Fine Gold, 32 GB)', 'Moto E4 Plus (Iron Gray, 32 GB)', 'Intex Aqua 5.5 VR (Champagne, White, 8 GB)', 'Lenovo K8 Plus (Venom Black, 32 GB)', 'Redmi Note 4 (Dark Grey, 64 GB)', 'Panasonic Eluga Ray (Gold, 16 GB)', 'Moto C Plus (Pearl White, 16 GB)', 'Moto C Plus (Starry Black, 16 GB)', 'Moto C Plus (Fine Gold, 16 GB)', 'Lenovo K8 Plus (Fine Gold, 32 GB)', 'Panasonic Eluga Ray 700 (Champagne Gold, 32 GB)', 'Panasonic Eluga I5 (Gold, 16 GB)', 'OPPO F5 (Black, 64 GB)', 'Lenovo K8 Plus (Fine Gold, 32 GB)', 'Moto X4 (Super Black, 64 GB)', 'Swipe ELITE Sense- 4G with VoLTE', 'Swipe ELITE Sense- 4G with VoLTE']


['14,999', '9,999', '14,999', '11,999', '9,999', '17,999', '11,999', '9,999', '9,999', '4,499', '9,999', '11,999', '6,999', '6,999', '6,999', '6,999', '9,999', '9,999', '6,499', '24,990', '10,999', '22,999', '5,555', '5,555']


['4 GB RAM | 64 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 128 GB', '5.5 inch Full HD Display', '12MP + 12MP Dual Rear Camera | 5MP Front Camera', '3080 mAh Li-polymer Battery', 'Qualcomm Snapdragon 625 64 bit Octa Core 2GHz Processor', 'Android Nougat 7.1.2 | Stock Android Version', 'Android One Smartphone - with confirmed upgrades to Android Oreo and Android P', 'Brand Warranty of 1 Year Available for Mobile and 6 Months for Accessories', .....]
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Is it now readable sir, any help regarding the problem's solution would be helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go. I think this is what your expected output was:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?count=40&otracker=categorytree&p=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=tyy%2C4io')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
for items in soup.select("._1UoZlX"):
    name = items.select("._3wU53n")[0].text
    price = items.select("._1vC4OE._2rQ-NK")[0].text
    specifics = ' '.join([item.text for item in items.select(".tVe95H")])
    print("Name: {}\nPrice: {}\nSpecification: {}\n".format(name,price,specifics))
```

Output of a single lead:

```
Name: Mi A1 (Black, 64 GB)
Price: ₹14,999
Specification: 4 GB RAM | 64 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 128 GB 5.5 inch Full HD Display 12MP + 12MP Dual Rear Camera | 5MP Front Camera 3080 mAh Li-polymer Battery Qualcomm Snapdragon 625 64 bit Octa Core 2GHz Processor Android Nougat 7.1.2 | Stock Android Version Android One Smartphone - with confirmed upgrades to Android Oreo and Android P Brand Warranty of 1 Year Available for Mobile and 6 Months for Accessories
```

Comment: Have you executed the code? What's the feedback? When someone tries to solve your problem, at least try to be responsive. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the very very late response, my project had stopped on web scrapping so was not using it anymore. But thank you. It worked.